# Grouping a list of objects by parent using linq to output child elements

Tags: c#, linq

I have a silly problem with a linq groupby I just cant get to work on my own.

Basically I have a list of items that I am trying to group together by its parentId outing the details

```
var list = new List<GroupItem>()
{
    new GroupItem() {Id = 1, Name = ".net"},
    new GroupItem() {Id = 2, Name = "asp.net", ParentId = 1},
    new GroupItem(){Id = 3,Name = "c#",ParentId = 1},
    new GroupItem(){Id = 4,Name = "php"},
    new GroupItem(){Id = 5,Name = "zend",ParentId = 4}
};

var group = from g in list
            group g by g.ParentId ==null
                into grouped
            select new
            {
                FrameworkId = grouped.Key,
                Items = (from g in list
                        where g.ParentId==g.ParentId
                        select g).ToList()

            };

foreach (var gi in group)
{

    Console.WriteLine(gi.FrameworkId);
    foreach (var item in gi.Items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't explained your expected output or what's actually happening. Does it compile but give the wrong results? Not compile at all? Compile but throw an exception? Please give more details. (`where g.ParentId == g.ParentId` seems like a bad idea to me...). Note that you're not grouping by parent ID... you're grouping by "whether the parent ID is null or not".

Comment: You are grouping on condition `g.ParentId == null`?

Comment: Sorry yes it compiles. Basically I am trying to output the framework id in the list there is .net and php - .net has the id 1 and php has 4. Within each of these frameworks I am trying to out the related child elements. .net has Ids 2 & 3 and php has 4. Does that clear it up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You query seems to be too complicated:

1. You should group by `ParentId` for items that have it not null
2. You do not need to find the items again by matching `ParentId` because `GroupBy` operator does it for you

My preferred solution:

```
list.Where(x => x.ParentId != null)
    .GroupBy(x => x.ParentId, 
             (key, elements) => 
                new {
                  FrameworkId = key,
                  Items = elements.ToList()
                })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thats awesome thank you Konrad! yes I think I was overthinking it too much after a long week :( Sorry if I wanted to get the parent name. What would I need to change?

Comment: The simplest solution is to find it by the inner query, so instead of `FrameworkId` you can write `FrameworkName = list.First(i => i.Id == key).Name`

Comment: Ok, thats what I thought to but wasnt 100% sure. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can Directlly use this query for filtering Data.

if you want the data which don't have ParentID then you can use below mentioned query

```
 var gr = list.Where(p => p.ParentId == 0).ToList();
```

and if you want the data who have the Parent Id then you can use below mentioned code

```
 var gr1 = list.Where(p => p.ParentId != 0).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution:

```
 list.Where(x => x.ParentId != null)
  .GroupBy(x => x.ParentId)
  .Select(x => new ParentViewModel {
     ParentId = x.Key.ParentId,
     Parent = x.ToList()
  })
  .ToList();
```

Now you will get child items in Parent object of `ParentViewModel`, e.g. `Parent.Items`